# Speed up insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have three tables InnoDB, those three have some foreign keys.

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_member` (
  `id_member` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_member`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`password`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=107 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_notification`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_notification` (
  `id_notification` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Notification ID',
  `type` enum('notification','announcement') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'notification',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Title',
  `notification` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Body',
  `datestart` int(13) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date when the notification will start to be deployed',
  `dateend` int(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_notification`),
  KEY `datestart` (`datestart`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_notification_member`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_notification_member` (
  `id_notification_member` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
  `id_notification` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Notification ID',
  `id_member` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Member ID',
  `status` enum('read','unread') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unread' COMMENT 'Defines if the notification was viewed already or not',
  `timestamp` int(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Time when the notification was saw',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_notification_member`),
  KEY `id_notification` (`id_notification`),
  KEY `id_member` (`id_member`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Constraints for table `tbl_notification_member`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_notification_member`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_notification_member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_member`) REFERENCES `tbl_member` (`id_member`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_notification_member_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_notification`) REFERENCES `tbl_notification` (`id_notification`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So as you can see if I delete one notification, the relation between the notifications and the members will be deleted on cascade, which is awesome, but the problem is when I tried to insert thousands of rows. Is there any way to do this in some way like cascade? Using indexes or something like that? (I've another relations in the tables I've remove, for example sections, so you can add notifications for only one section and delimit the number of users that will receive the notification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase it by [Innodb Performance Optimization Basics](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/)

> Also check if your application can run in READ-COMMITED isolation mode
>   – if it does – set it to be default as
>   transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED. This option has some performance
>   benefits, especially in locking in 5.0 and even more to come with
>   MySQL 5.1 and row level replication.

Also check [this](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.in/2007/04/innodb-performance-optimization.html).

Comment: Don't really answer my question, but gives me a clue of where to search.

Comment: I can't see why this was selected as an answer