# Mysql+Mybatis insertBatch rate

Tags: mysql, insert, batch-processing, mybatis

1.How many records can mysql insert in one minute?

2.if work with mybatis,what is the rate?

config is:

```
  <insert id="insertBatch" >
  insert into table(id, task_id, coupon_id, 
  user_id, expire_time, create_time, 
  update_time, is_deleted) values 
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator="," >
  (#{item.id,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{item.taskId,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{item.couponId,jdbcType=INTEGER}, 
  #{item.userId,jdbcType=INTEGER}, #{item.expireTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, #{item.createTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, 
  #{item.updateTime,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, #{item.isDeleted,jdbcType=TINYINT})
    </foreach>
  </insert>
```

3.How to achieve higher efficiency for insert?

Comment: As a general rule you should use prepared statements. If you are inserting into innodb, transactions will help. Insert speed depends on your hardware.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452412/speed-up-insert-in-mysql and make sure you use batch insert via mybatis batch executor